# Целесообразна ли такая обработка $_POST?

Tags: php, post

Может ли злоумышленник отправить методом `$_POST` какую нибудь билеберду, в обход формы? Например, я ожидаю получить `$_POST['userName']` и `$_POST['userEmail']` , а мне приходит `$_POST['iAm']` и `$_POST['coolHacker']`. 
В таком случае, если для меня критичны названия полей, и далее я их использую в своём скрипте - это может нарушить его работу. Что бы не работать напрямую с массивом `$_POST`, целесообразно ли будет его обработать следующим способом?

```
$formData = ['field1Name' => '', 'field2Name' => ''];
       foreach ($formData as $fieldName => $value) {
           if (isset($_POST[$fieldName])) {
               $formData[$fieldName] = $_POST[$fieldName];
           }
       }
```

Comment: Очевидно, всё зависит от того, что именно там далее в вашем скрипте

Comment: @andreymal, собственно меня интересует, может ли злоумышленник отправить методом $_POST какую нибудь билеберду, в обход формы?

Comment: Один из принципов безопасности — не доверять никаким входящим данным. Если ожидаются какие-то предопределенные поля, то нужно их и принимать для обработки. Если поле предназначено для email, то оно проходит валидацию, что это корректный адрес. Если это имя, то фильтруете входящие данные на наличие script, тэгов и т.п. В итоге что осталось и отправляется дальше по коду. Если что-то не так, то рубрим выполнение и выдаём ошибку.

Comment: @RomanAndreev может конечно, но совсем не факт, что это на что-нибудь повлияет, если скрипт эту билеберду трогать не будет

Comment: @MAX к вашему сведению, `very."(),:;<>[]".VERY."very@\\\\\\ \"very<script>alert(1)</script>".unusual@strange.example.com` это вполне корректный email адрес согласно RFC :)

Comment: @andreymal Думаю, что функция filter_var() выдаст false на такой адрес. :)

Comment: @MAX если так, то значит она нарушает стандарт и её нельзя использовать ;)

Comment: @andreymal Почему нельзя? Задача — отфильтровать данные. Она с ней справляется. Если в адресе <script>, то не зависимо от стандарта, такой текст нужно рубитиь на корню. :) Или вы реально можете зарегистрировать такой адрес электронной почты? ;-)

Comment: Белый список - хорошая идея. Фильтровать на наличие тегов - плохая. Просто корректно экранируйте данные в представлении. Для html - это htmlspecialchars. Не экранируйте ничего заранее. Данные всегда могут понадобиться в представлении другого типа с иным экранированием)

Comment: @MAX на собственном почтовом сервере — почему бы и не зарегистрировать :D (но мне лень)

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего Вам не удастся ни отправить, ни получить письмо с чужого почтового сервера) Стандарты стандартами, а политики политиками)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать функцию [array_intersect_key](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), выглядит более красиво:

```
$fields = ['field1Name', 'field2Name'];
$formData = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fields));
```

Результат будет тот же, но меньше кода.

По поводу вопроса - может ли добавить? Легко, просто меняет исходный код страницы или если через curl - добавляет параметры.

Comment: спасибо, но всё же это не отвечает на мой основной  вопрос :)

Comment: @RomanAndreev дополнил ответ, можно это легко сделать - если ответить в двух словах )

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос безопасности в проекте должен быть реализован более глобально. С таким подходом вы точно где-то допустите ошибку. Пилите проект как угодно, а потом отдельно займитесь безопасностью. Найдите все шлюзы для данных и добавьте валидаторы для того чтобы не допустить попадания в обработку нецелевых данных.

Comment: `Пилите проект как угодно, а потом` - таким образом можно попасть в ситуацию, когда придётся всё делать с нуля.

Comment: `Найдите все шлюзы данных` - проблема в том, что в php "шлюзами данных" являются суперглобальные переменные($_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST/$_COOKIE etc.). Если заранее не ограничить к ним доступ, искать придётся долго.